# Getting a custom property inside an Option element of a Select element

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Browser Independence issue Code Working for IE but not for Firefox and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8641495/browser-independence-issue-code-working-for-ie-but-not-for-firefox-and-chrome)

I'm trying to support some old code, and I have an option element inside a Select element in html:

```
<select onChange="selectURL(this)" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:12;" id="select1" name="select1">

<option ThisCourse="80921" TITLE="- _ ~ : /  =  ’ ; . , ?  ) (.2\" CLASS="" ID="a368890534077645903f263b5ddc105f" VALUE="/Eclass/CourseFrames.asp?vcCourseGUID=a368890534077645903f263b5ddc105f&amp;vcCourseName=%2D+%5F+%7E+%3A+%2F++%3D++%92+%3B+%2E+%2C+%3F++%29+%28%2E2%5C&amp;vcCourseID=80921&amp;NewWin=0&amp;language=">- _ ~ : /  =  ’ ; . , ?  ) (.2\</option>
```

There's some javascript running on that site, and it's trying to do this:

```
for (i=0; i<SelectElement.options.length;i++)
if (SelectElement.options[i].ThisCourse == CourseID)
SelectElement.selectedIndex = i
```

In IE, this works fine - it can manage to get to ThisCourse. However, Firefox and Chrome do not understand SelectElement.options[i].ThisCourse

I'm guessing there's some modern way to get "ThisCourse", but I don't know how.

Comment: As you have already found the answer it's probably worth deleting your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the getAttribute method instead of accessing the property, like this...

```
if (SelectElement.options[i].getAttribute('ThisCourse') == CourseID)
```

IE generally treats property values and attributes alike, however, they are different.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SelectElement.options[i].getAttribute("ThisCourse");
```

You should move towards using the HTML5 "data-" attributes.

http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/